# How can I tell if an object is overwritten using the Amazon S3 sdk?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk

If I use `PutObject` in the Amazon S3 SDK is there a way to tell if the object in the bucket pre-existed (was overwritten) without fetching it first? There is the `x-amz-version-id` header but thats always the latest version, while I want the previous version instead.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is using ETag's to detect if the items changed. It's possible to only upload the item when changed using Etags. But that's not exactly what you want I think.

Comment: Do you have s3 versioning enabled?